# OpenVPN with IPv6 drops packages

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, ipv6

I am using OpenVPN (build from tarball) and have a /112 subnet. My server is configured to use tun. IPv4 is working correctly, but IPv6 has some problems:

- ping6 ipv6.google.com gives no reply.
- When I add the from OpenVPN advertised ip6 address and remove it after that, it works.

My idea is: the ICMP is leaving the server, but isn't coming back, because the address assigned to the vpn client isn't added in any interface - the server is ignoring the incoming packet.

How can I change this behaviour? tcpdump shows the outgoing packet. I can ping the openvpn server from the client.

Answer (score 0):

The proper configuration is to have one link prefix assigned to the physical network interface on the VPN server and have a different prefix routed to the server from which you allocate a link prefix for the virtual network interface used by the VPN software. Unless you have specific reasons to do otherwise, you should make each of the link prefixes a /64. The routed could be a /64 or shorter.

Of those three prefixes involved you only mention that one is a /112 without mentioning which one of them it is. This makes me think you might be trying to use one single /112 for different purposes without even realizing what each of those different purposes is.

There are hacks one can use to turn part of a link prefix into a routed prefix, those hacks do however waste capacity on the router and requires better understanding of the protocols you are dealing with, so my recommendation is to use a real routed prefix.

If it is completely impossible for you to get a routed prefix either from your current provider or by switching to another provider, you can proxy neighbor discovery between the physical and virtual interfaces. [ndppd](http://priv.nu/projects/ndppd/) promises to be able to do that. I haven't tested that particular tool, but I know from previous experiments that it is possible to do it.

Comment: My provider only assigns me a /112.

Comment: You should ask your provider for a routed /60. If your provider won't give you that, you should consider moving to a more serious provider. You could use a hack to turn one /113 out of that /112 into a routed prefix, but it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: I already asked my provider - he wouldn't. It's a VPN in another country, and more or less the cheapest provider.

Comment: Is it your own VPN server, or are you only running the client yourself?

Comment: It's a KVM container.